# Angular 2 button click animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, angular

I want to animate a scale-down-then-scale-back effect on every button clicks. Here are what I tried:

```
<button (click)="clickMe()" [ngClass]="{'animated-button': animated}">Button</button>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
@keyframes buttonClickAnimation {
  0% {transform: scale(0.8);}
  100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
.animated-button {
  animation: buttonClickAnimation 0.5s;
}
```

Here's my component:

```
...
animated: boolean = false;

clickMe() {
  this.animated = true;
}
```

This only works on the very first click, which makes sense because my `animated` variable never gets set back to `false`. However, if I set it back to `false` in `clickMe()`, the animation wouldn't have time to execute. Maybe this isn't even the right way to implement this. Please advise! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay to setting the animated variable to false.

```
clickMe() {
  this.animated = true;
  delay(500).then(() => this.animated = false);
}

async function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: Turning this into a directive would be nice, no? (to avoid having to deal with an otherwise rather useless state variable redundandly on every occasion)

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a boolean (true/false) value by appending a `!`

```
animated: boolean = false;

clickMe() {
  this.animated = !this.animated;
}
```